# Adding a link to a worksheet to a cell in a different worksheet within the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

see Title. I want to add a hyperlink (which directs to a chart-sheet) to a cell in an index sheet so the user can click on the link in the index sheet and it takes them to the chart.

I've tried listing the entire path after `Address:=`, so `Address:=ThisWorkbook.("Charts Index")`, I've tried setting the path equal to a string and variant, I've tried replicating nearly every similar problem on the internet. I've tried using `.Hyperlinks` and `.SubAddress`in multiple different way, etc.

```
Set newWs = ThisWorkbook.Charts.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))

Dim index_ws As Worksheet
Set index_ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Charts Index")

Sheet3.define_emptyRow

With index_ws
    .Cells(emptyRow, 1) = chTitle_textB.Value
    .Cells(emptyRow, 2) = shName_textB.Value
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(emptyRow, 3), _
    Address:="", SubAddress:=newWs, _
    TextToDisplay:="see Chart"
End With
```

I want this code to add a hyperlink to my index page and when I click on it, I want it to take me to the chart.

Comment: Insert > Link > Place in this document.

Comment: I don't think you can create a link to a Chart sheet.  See for example: https://www.sumproduct.com/thought/hyperlinking-chart-sheets

Answer (score 1):

Manually,

Insert > Link > Place in this document

via VBA

```
.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
 "Sheet1!R1C1", TextToDisplay:="Click Me"
```

(Replace Selection with a cell reference.)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add code to post. I've added it now. The problem with this code is the sheet I'm trying to link to gets added immediately prior to this operation taking place, and therefore I cant define it simply like "Sheet1!R1C1" because I won;t know what sheet # it is

Comment: @Ben I thought you wanted a link back to your Index page.  In which case you would use replace Sheet1 with the name of your index sheet.

Comment: No - sorry for not being more clear. I want an index sheet which will house links (or some other object) which will take the user to the chart. This is intended to make it easier for the user to find a specific chart after there are a hundred or so charts generated (and polluting the 'sheet' ribbon at the bottom.)

Comment: So you would get a handle to the new sheet (`Set mySheet=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add` then replace *Sheet1* with `MySheet.Name`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly but have you tried using the "**Insert hyperlink**" tool (button) provided by Excel? There is a menu option called "Place in This Document" where you can select the sheet or defined name you want to link it to (as a hyperlink) within the same workbook. You can specify the cell, the worksheet, or even the defined name.

Here is a screen shot of how it looks like:
[Insert Hyperlink Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUXOA.png)

I hope this helps! It is not a VBA code but I thought it might be what you are looking for (with a simple solution).

V

Comment: I'm looking for VBA code that can do it automatically, thanks anyway though :)

Comment: "I want to add a hyperlink (which directs to a **chart**-sheet)" - you cannot use Insert hyperlink to do this